# Is using "Sirs" when addressing a group of men incorrect?

Tags: word-usage, formality

When I was in the Army, I was taught that you addressed an individual officer as "Sir" or "Ma'am". You address groups of officers as "Gentlemen" or "Ladies", not "Sirs" or "Ma'ams".

Example:
Approaching a group of male officers, I would salute and say "Good morning, gentlemen" not "Good morning, sirs."

Now, whenever someone says "Sirs", I cringe.  It sounds as bad as if someone said "Ma'ams".

**But is it *actually* incorrect, or is it strictly an Army thing?**

Note: I'm not talking about the rare situation where you might be introducing someone to a group of knights and saying "May I present Sirs Galahad and Lancelot"

Comment: Surely the equivalent of *sirs* is *mesdames*, not *ma'ams*.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466248/what-is-the-plural-of-sir

Comment: You defenitely use  *Dear Sirs* ,  rather than  *Dear Gentlmen*  to start a business or formal letter.

Comment: To answer your question: no, there's nothing wrong with it. Yes, the proper way to introduce Galahad and Lancelot is "Sirs Galahad and Lancelot".  Yes, it makes lots of people cringe; it's unctuous, slimey, servile. Unlike @user240918, I would never start a letter "Sirs,", and I'd wince a little if I received one. But that's probably a cultural thing; every country has its culture, and I've noticed eg Indian English correspondence is much more explicitly hierarchical and hyperformal than the prevailing American norm of treating everyone as equals (even when there is a difference in hierarchy).

Comment: @user240918 The answer talking about "vocative" basically answers this question